# rails radio_button and label in two different lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, radio-button

I'm pretty new to CSS.

I'm having radio buttons in my app

```
<%= f.radio_button :gender, true %> <%= f.label :gender, "Male" %>        
<%= f.radio_button :gender, false%> <%= f.label :gender, "Female" %>
```

but the page show the radio button and label in two different lines, like

```
O
Male
O
Female
```

How can I make it at the same line? Like

```
  O Male
  O Female
```

Thanks

With

```
input[type="radio"], label{
     float:left;
}
label{
 clear:left;
}
```

The page looks like

```
O
Male O
Female
```

Tried several different browser and the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

write like this in your css:

```
input[type="radio"], label{
 display:inline-block;
 *display:inline/*For IE7*/
 *zoom:1;
}
```

**UPDATED**

Write like this:

```
input[type="radio"], label{
     float:left;
    }
input{
 clear:left;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/nuyqd/

Comment: Using this makes it looks like O Male O Female.I'd like to have Male and Female button in two lines.(updated question to make it more clear) How could this be done? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found this CSS to be better since it didn't jam the radio button and the text together.

```
input[type="radio"], label{
     float:left; margin-left: 5px;
    }
input{
 clear:left;;
}
```